# Javascript .createElement & .appendChild Issue (Includes for and if)

Tags: javascript, createelement

I am a pretty novice javascript user. I need some help debugging this code. What I intend this to do is based on the amount of values in the list, is create a 3 column wide table to display each. BTW the whole html formatting is set up with grid.

The error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')

HTML (inside body):

```
<section id="db_gallery">
      <table id="gallery_table"></table>
      <script src="autogallery.js"></script>
</section>
```

JS in autogallery.js:

```
const gallery_table = document.getElementById("gallery_table");
const list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

for (let i of list) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        let newRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
        var idName = "newRowItem";
        idName.concat(i);
        newRowItem.setAttribute("id", idName);
        gallery_table.appendChild(newRowItem);
    }

    let newColItem = document.createElement('th');
    newColItem.textContent = i;

    idName.appendChild(newColItem);
    console.log(idName);
}
```

Also it would be a big help if any suggestions were simple to understand. If it means anything I will eventually be linking this to a phpmyadmin database as the values in the array.
Thanks!

Comment: `i` takes on the values `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"` so `i % 3 === 0` will never be true... and so `idName` will never get set... and so `idName.appendChild(newColItem);` will fail...

Comment: Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to iterate the array, that passes the index too. An important note: Ids within the document must be unique, remove the ids of the rows, you don't need those at all.

Comment: @Ryan, when are you executing the script ? are you making sure the dom is ready before executing the script ?

Comment: @gvmani, I am calling the script after the table is made, is that right, sorry I have little knowledge of DOMs at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should `newRowItem.appendChild` instead of `idName` because `newRowItem` is the element you've created.

And second when using `for...of` `i` is the element not the index, so it's better to use `for` in your case.

And last you shouldn't use `newRowItem` outside the scope because you declared it with `let` inside `if` caluse.

this should be correct:

```
const gallery_table = document.getElementById("gallery_table");
let list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var idName = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            let newRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
            idName = "newRowItem";
            idName = idName.concat(list[i]);
            newRowItem.setAttribute("id", idName);
            gallery_table.appendChild(newRowItem);
            let newColItem = document.createElement('th');
            newColItem.textContent = list[i];
            newRowItem.appendChild(newColItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is outputting only A and D on seperate lines, is there a way to re-organise it  to have A, B and C appear on the first line, then D, E and F on the second?

Comment: @RyanC What do you think you can do with the dynamic id? It's an antipattern, it's error prone and hard to maintain. Don't use dynamic ids, don't use ids for any table element, they simply are not needed.

Comment: you should handle that in else and use another for to do that

Comment: @RyanC
Assigning "newRowItem" to idName in a for loop is not efficient.
As this variable is used at only one place, it should be removed (declaration and assignment) and you should use this instead: `newRowItem.setAttribute("id", "newRowItem" + i);`  -->  JavaScript will do type conversion and concat the string with `i` converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
newRowItem.appendChild(newColItem)
```

instead of

```
idName.appendChild(newColItem)
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop with index to do modulo operation on list indexes.

```
    let newRowItem;
    for (int i=0 ; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            newRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
            var idName = "newRowItem";
            idName.concat(i);
            newRowItem.setAttribute("id", idName);
            gallery_table.appendChild(newRowItem);
        }
        if(newRowItem){
            let tag = i < 3 ? 'th' : 'td';
            let newColItem = document.createElement(tag);
            newColItem.textContent = list[i];
            newRowItem.appendChild(newColItem);
            console.log(newRowItem);
        }
   }`
```